# How to use App service Provider for this

Tags: php, laravel

I am called all model Account, Post, comment, Task and Interaction

But I have a an Error. This is the Error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}() must be an
>   instance of App\Account, instance of App\Post given

This is my code:

```
public function boot(){
    Post::saved(function(Account $account, Account $from, Post $post){
        if ($post->isIntractable()) {
            $interaction = Interaction::add($post, $from, $account);
            Task::add($interaction);
        }
    });

    Comment::saved(function ($account, $from, Comment $comment){
        $interaction = Interaction::add($comment, $from, $account);
        Task::add($interaction);

        $raw_data = json_decode($comment->raw_data, true);
        $replies = Comment::makeOrUpdateGraphEdge(array_get($raw_data, 'comments'));
        foreach ($replies as $reply) {
            $raw_data = json_decode($reply->raw_data, true);
            $from = $this->cacheAccount($raw_data['from']);
            $this->cacheReplies($account, $from, $comment, $reply);
        }
    });
}

private function cachePost(Account $account, Account $from, Post $post) { 
    $post->account()->associate($account);
    $post->from()->associate($from);
    $post->save();
    /* if ($post->isIntractable()) {
        $interaction = Interaction::add($post, $from, $account); 
        Task::add($interaction);
    }*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Model events expect only one parameter which is the model that triggered that event. In your case for example:

```
Post::saved(function(Post $post){
    if ($post->isIntractable()) {
        $interaction = Interaction::add($post, $from, $account); // this will throw error as the variables are not recognized by the event.
        Task::add($interaction);
    }
});
```

If you need to pass more parameters, you need to find a way to attach those parameters to the `Post` model before triggering the `save()` action.